# Restricting certain files from appearing in search results in Drupal 7

Tags: files

I would like to upload multiple revisions of documents, but only for the Latest ones to be displayed in the search results. For example. I will have the following pages and policies on each:

Apples
 Apples price policy V3
 Apples price policy V2
 Apples price policy V1
 Apples growing policy V3
 Apples growing policy V2
 Apples growing policy V1

Pears
 Pears price policy V2
 Pears price policy V1
 Pears growing policy V4
 Pears growing policy V3
 Pears growing policy V2
 Pears growing policy V1

However, I only want the following files/documents to be searchable/displayed in the search results:

Apples price policy V3
 Apples growing policy V3
 Pears price policy V2
 Pears growing policy V4

How do I do this?